# ¿Como puedo agregar el id de un usuario a un archivo de redireccion en html?

Tags: php, html, variables, redirección

Este es el html que uso para redireccionar, ¿Como puedo hacer que al final de la url donde dice "subid=" se agregue el id de un usuario registrado en mi pagina web? es decir, cuando el usuario juan con id= 57 entre a www.ejemplo.com/redirect.html, lo lleve a https://www.publicidad.de/lead.php?id=1&sid=1&usubid=57. agregando ese 57 al final que seria el id del usuario juan. aqui abajo dejo el codigo de mi html.

```
<html>
<head>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" 
CONTENT="5;URL=https://www.publicidad.de/lead.php?id=1&sid=1&usubid=">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/> 
<title>Redireccionando...</title><script type="text/javascript">
</script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>Estas siendo redirecionado</h1></center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Podrias poner el codigo de como realizar la parte del id=1 en tu url ..

Answer (score 0):

Existen dos métodos con los que el navegador puede enviar información al servidor:

- Método HTTP GET. Información se envía de forma visible
- Método HTTP POST. Información se envía de forma no visible

Antes de que el navegador envíe la información proporcionada, la codifica mediante URL encoding, dando como resultado un Query String. Esta codificación es un esquema de keys y values separados por un ampersand &

Lo que tu deseas hacer es por el metodo GET:

**El método GET**

envía la información codificada del usuario en el header del HTTP request, directamente en la URL. La página web y la información codificada se separan por un interrogante ?:

```
www.ejemplo.com/index.htm?key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3...
```

Ejemplo sencillo de formulario html con el método GET:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="formget.php" method="get">
    Nombre: <input type="text" name="nombre"><br>
    Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
Hola <?php isset($_GET["nombre"]) ? print $_GET["nombre"] : ""; ?><br>
Tu email es: <?php isset($_GET["email"]) ? print $_GET["email"] : ""; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

La url que resulta de hacer click en submit es de la forma:

```
formget.php?nombre=peter&email=peter%40ejemplo.com
```

En este caso @ es un carácter especial y se codifica.

**Método HTTP POST**

Con el método HTTP POST también se codifica la información, pero ésta se envía a través del body del HTTP Request, por lo que no aparece en la URL.

- El método POST no tiene límite de cantidad de información a enviar.
- La información proporcionada no es visible, por lo que se puede
  enviar información sensible.

**ejemplo sencillo de metodo post**

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="formpost.php" method="post">
    Nombre: <input type="text" name="nombre"><br>
    Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
Hola <?php isset($_POST["nombre"]) ? print $_POST["nombre"] : ""; ?><br>
Tu email es: <?php isset($_POST["email"]) ? print $_POST["email"] : ""; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Se puede comprobar que la información no se muestra en la url. Te recomiendo leer: 
[Documentacion Oficial Metodo Post y Get](http://php.net/manual/es/language.variables.external.php)